# Image doesn't fit in screen React-native

Tags: react-native, imagebackground

I have an imagebackground that's working but exceeds in height, I don't know how to make it fit to the screen. In fact, it 'cuts' the top of the image.

The original image :

[image]

my code :

```
  <ImageBackground
source={require("../../assets/images/background-stats.jpg")}
style={{flex: 1,
width: "100%",
height: "100%",
resizeMode: 'contain',
justifyContent: 'center'
}}
```

> 

the result :
[image]

Comment: Try resizeMode: 'stretch',

Comment: thanks for answering. I just tried and I have the exact same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'cover' }}
```

or

```
imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'stretch' }}
```

Comment: Even though it was down-voted (by someone that his answer did not help) it is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I tried to change resizeMode stretch / cover /contain/center, even removing height and width, nothing happens.

Comment: Look at my answer. It is inside the "imageStyle" prop, not the "style" prop

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as useful for future generations (it is currently marked not useful as someone down-voted)